# Mysql query strings search contain "/" resulting 0 results

Tags: mysql

I want to search a specific value for the model_type columns. But the problem is, I can't query it using `like` or `=` using the **exactly same** value. 
Here is my table model:

```
| id | model_type      | model_id |
|----|-----------------|----------|
| 1  | App\Models\User | 2        |
| 2  | App\Models\Link | 3        |
| 3  | App\Models\Link | 4        |
```

and here are the settings
Table schema: `latin1`
Default Charset for `model_type` : `utf8mb4`
Collation for `model_type`: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
Data type for `model_type`: `varchar(191)`

when i try to search using

`SELECT * FROM models WHERE model_type = "App\Models\Link";`

or
`SELECT * FROM models WHERE model_type like "App\Models\Link";`

it returns 0 rows.

After some digging when i tried to query model_type values that have `\` using these query 
`SELECT * FROM models WHERE model_type like '%\Link%'` it will return the rows,
 but when i tried `SELECT * FROM models WHERE model_type like '%s\Link%'` it returns 0 rows

I have tried to use **COLLATE**, and the results are 0 rows too.
example: `SELECT * FROM models where model_type = "App\Models\Link" COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: Did you try escaping the `\\` ? (`App\\Models\\Link`)

Comment: Study carefully: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a string literal in mysql, `\` needs to be escaped, as `\\`.  But in a like operation, `\` is also used to escape the `%` and `_` metacharacters, so to have a `\` in a like operand, it needs to be escaped as `\\`.  Putting those together, when you have a string literal used in a like operand, you need `\\\\`:

```
 SELECT * FROM models WHERE model_type like "App\\\\Models\\\\Link";
```

But like is not appropriate there, since you are looking for an exact match.  Using `=`, you only need to escape once:

```
 SELECT * FROM models WHERE model_type = "App\\Models\\Link";
```